# Where can I track campaigns in Google Analytics?

Tags: google, google-analytics

I'm trying to track campaigns in Google Analytics. I was able to create them, but I'm not sure where I can check the stats for them in Google Analytics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Traffic Sources -> Sources -> Campaigns.

You can only track campaigns if you have integrated analytics with an Adwords account/manually tagged URLs with the URL builder

http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en-GB&answer=1033867

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hi Jack thanks for the answer. When I create it with the URL builder, I give it a campaign name, but on analytics that campaign doesn't seem to show up. How do I tie the two together?

Comment: Have you definitely started receiving traffic through that URL? Also remember that Google analytics can be delayed by up to 12 hours. the best way to check if it's working is by opening up a new browser, ensuring you're not logged into Google and then click on the link you created. If you then navigate to the GA live view page you should be able to see all the information there - a great way to check if you've set up campaign tagging correctly.. hope that makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

Campaign data is displayed under Traffic Sources > Campaigns in the left hand menu

Answer (score -1):

If you're using Chrome browser, you can try use the chrome extension which has Bitly feature and pre-configured sets for daily basis tags usage.
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-url-buil/gaidpiakchgkapdgbnoglpnbccdepnpk

Comment: Welcome to Webmasters. Your answer doesn't appear to answer the original question. The question's already been answered.